# Python: Capitalize a word using string.format()

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is it possible to capitalize a word using string formatting? For example,

```
"{user} did such and such.".format(user="foobar")
```

should return "Foobar did such and such."

Note that I'm well aware of `.capitalize()`; however, here's a (very simplified version of) code I'm using:

```
printme = random.choice(["On {date}, {user} did la-dee-dah. ",
                         "{user} did la-dee-dah on {date}. "
                         ])

output = printme.format(user=x,date=y)
```

As you can see, just defining `user` as `x.capitalize()` in the `.format()` doesn't work, since then it would also be applied (incorrectly) to the first scenario. And since I can't predict fate, there's no way of knowing which `random.choice` would be selected in advance. What can I do?

*Addt'l note:* Just doing `output = random.choice(['xyz'.format(),'lmn'.format()])` (in other words, formatting each string individually, and then using `.capitalize()` for the ones that need it) isn't a viable option, since `printme` is actually choosing from ~40+ strings.

Comment: Why are you arbitrarily recasing usernames?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Username is actually equal to either a username **or** a pronoun -- for pronouns, one wouldn't always capitalize them.

Comment: Wait... you'd change the display case of a username, but not a pronoun? Why would you do that? People expect their usernames to be exactly the case they typed into the box.

Comment: @user2357112 Not in this project :p No, seriously, I'm working with a dataset where I **know** for a fact that each username is capitalized already (it's required by the software, which I didn't write).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create your own subclass of [`string.Formatter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) which will allow you to recognize a custom [conversion](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) that you can use to recase your strings.

```
myformatter.format('{user!u} did la-dee-dah on {date}, and {pronoun!l} liked it. ',
                      user=x, date=y, pronoun=z)
```

Comment: And just for reference in case anyone else has this question, [here is the function that needs to be changed](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/string.py#l602).

Comment: s/changed/overridden/

Answer (score 18):

As said @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, create a subclass of [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.Formatter) allow you to extend/change the format string processing.

In your case, you have to overload the method `convert_field`

```
from string import Formatter
class ExtendedFormatter(Formatter):
    """An extended format string formatter

    Formatter with extended conversion symbol
    """
    def convert_field(self, value, conversion):
        """ Extend conversion symbol
        Following additional symbol has been added
        * l: convert to string and low case
        * u: convert to string and up case

        default are:
        * s: convert with str()
        * r: convert with repr()
        * a: convert with ascii()
        """

        if conversion == "u":
            return str(value).upper()
        elif conversion == "l":
            return str(value).lower()
        # Do the default conversion or raise error if no matching conversion found
        return super(ExtendedFormatter, self).convert_field(value, conversion)

# Test this code

myformatter = ExtendedFormatter()

template_str = "normal:{test}, upcase:{test!u}, lowcase:{test!l}"


output = myformatter.format(template_str, test="DiDaDoDu")
print(output)
```

Comment: I believe your example has an error in it. Instead of having `return value` as the last line of `convert_field`, you should have returned the output of calling super, i.e.: `return super(ExtendedFormatter, self)...`

Comment: @peter.slizik indeed

Answer (score 12):

You can pass extra values and just not use them, like this lightweight option

```
printme = random.choice(["On {date}, {user} did la-dee-dah. ",
                         "{User} did la-dee-dah on {date}. "
                         ])

output = printme.format(user=x, date=y, User=x.capitalize())
```

The best choice probably depends whether you are doing this enough to need your own fullblown `Formatter`.

Comment: I like this approach! Yeah, I'm doing it on a larger scale (600+ messages, and various different functions -- not just capitalization), so it's not really applicable to my situation per say, but still something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 6):

In python 3.6+ you can use fstrings now. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

```
>>> txt = 'aBcD'
>>> f'{txt.upper()}'
'ABCD'
```

Comment: This would only solve the problem if OP inlined the f-string into `random.choice`, which he may or may not be able to do.