# Can you cast a string to upper case while formating

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, python-2.x

### **Motivation**

Suppose you have a string that is used twice in one string. However, in one case it is upper, and the other it is lower. If a dictionary is used, it would seem the solution would be to add a new element that is uppercase.

---

Suppose I have a python string ready to be formatted as:

```
string = "{a}_{b}_{c}_{a}"
```

With a desired output of:

> HELLO_by_hi_hello

I also have a dictionary ready as:

```
dictionary = {a: "hello", b: "bye", c: "hi"}
```

Without interacting with the dictionary to set a new element `d` as being `"HELLO"` such as:

```
dictionary['d'] = dictionary['a'].upper()
string = "{d}_{b}_{c}_{a}"
string.format(**dictionary)
print(string)
>>> HELLO_bye_hi_hello
```

Is there a way to set element `a` to always be uppercase in one case of the string? For example something like:

```
string= "{a:upper}_{b}_{c}_{a}"
string.format(**dictionary)
print(string)
>>> HELLO_bye_hi_hello
```

Comment: With [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (Python >= 3.6) you actually _can_ do that: `d = {"a": "hello", "b": "bye", "c": "hi"};
print(f"{d['a'].upper()}_{d['b']}_{d['c']}_{d['a']}")`. Taken from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411002/python-error-str-object-has-no-attribute-upper). Without you restricting this question to a Python version below 3.6, I'm tempted to mark this as a duplicate (hence the comment instead of an answer).

Comment: @shmee Unfortunately, I am working of 2.6.6, and I will mark it as such. As well, (I know a beggar shouldn't be a chooser) I'm not a huge fan of having to specify the dictionary name inside the print statement.

Comment: The cleanest way I can think of would be: `string.format(**{**dictionary, 'a' : dictionary['a'].upper()})` where you expand two dictionaries, the inner expand takes care of the `upper()` call and the other just passes the dict to the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't do that. 
In the simplest solution, you can write a lambda to capitalize the values in your string. Or you can subclass strnig.Formatter if you really want to achieve your goal that way.

Following link can help if you are going for the harder method.
[Python: Capitalize a word using string.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848202/python-capitalize-a-word-using-string-format)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it seems clear that there is no true way to do it in python.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do that:

```
string = "{d.upper()}_{b.lower()}_{c.lower()}_{a.lower()}"
```

Comment: "The times they are a changin" - Python

I assume this is a python-3.x thing?